# How to get unique values for multiple rows obtained via concatenation

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, concatenation

Im working in Oracle SQL. I have a source and a target table. I have to concatenate 2 columns from the source table as one column for the target table. In addition would need other columns as well from the source table to be mapped to different other columns in the target table. I have used concat function but in the result there are multiple records for the concatenated combination but I require only unique values to mapped to the target table.
I have tried using distinct but the row count is not matching. The Disctinct is applied to all other columns as well.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (T1.C1||T1.C2) AS T2.C1, T1.C3 AS T2.C2,
                TO_DATE('01/01/1900', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS T2.C3
FROM TABLE T1
WHERE <some cond..>

SIPP34  PDG III Lifestyle - Cash    Lifestyle   116 Open    01/01/1900
SIPP34  PDG III Lifestyle - Cash    Lifestyle   116 Open    01/01/1900
SIPP34  PDG III Lifestyle - Cash    Lifestyle   116 Open    01/01/1900
SIPP34  PDG III Lifestyle - Cash    Lifestyle   116 Open    01/01/1900
SIPP34  PDG III Lifestyle - Cash    Lifestyle   116 Open    01/01/1900
SIPP34  PDG III Lifestyle - Cash    Lifestyle   116 Open    01/01/1900
SIPP34  PDG III Lifestyle - Cash    Lifestyle   116 Open    01/01/1900
SIPP34  PDG III Lifestyle - Cash    Lifestyle   116 Open    01/01/1900
SIPP34  PDG III Lifestyle - Cash    Lifestyle   116 Open    01/01/1900
SIPP34  PDG III Lifestyle - Cash    Lifestyle   116 Open    01/01/1900
```

I ve got multiple rows like this in my query result. the first column is obtained by concatenating 2 different columns. My actual result should contain only one entry of this. 
In other words can distinct be applied to only one column (which is obtained as a result of concatenation) in a select statement. 
because if I use DISTINCT (T1.C1||T1.C2) the concatenation is working correctly but the distinct is applied to other columns as well and my result is missing few other rows.

Sorry I couldnt explain well more than this. Can anyone help pls.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Show some examples.  As written the only reason for multiple rows is that the rows are Not the same.  If you show some examples you can demonstrate what happens, and then what you actually want.  Once we know what scenarios you're dealing with, and how you want to handle them, we can show you how : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `distinct` is always applied to all columns - [from the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html), "Specify DISTINCT or UNIQUE if you want the database to return only one copy of each set of duplicate rows selected. These two keywords are synonymous. Duplicate rows are those with matching values for each expression in the select list." If you only want one row for the c1/c2 combo you would have to define *which* row the other column values are preserved for. But the example in your question seems to show duplicate rows, which is... confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understood well, if you want something similar to this

```
TABLE:test_test
Name    Mark
------- ------
ABC     10
DEF     10
GHI     10
JKL     20
MNO     20
PQR     30



mark count     names
---- -----     -----------
10       3     ABC,DEF,GHI
20       2     JKL,MNO
30       1     PQR
```

try using the wm_concat function

```
select mark, count(*), wm_concat(name) 
from test_test 
group by 
mark;
```

you can get more info on [http://www.dba-oracle.com/...](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_wm_concat_sql_function.htm)